# Copy one cell and paste down a column

Tags: vba, copy-paste

Been trying to figure out how to copy a cell from worksheet A and paste it down a column in Worksheet B until it matches the same amount of rows as an adjacent column. Take the following screenshot for example. How would I properly accomplish this in VBA? Been trying to figure this out for a while now. All I've been able to do is copy the cell and paste it adjacent to the last cell in the adjacent column instead of down the entire column. The worksheet I'm copying data from is pictured below.

Copy From SpreadSheet down below
[image: Copy From SpreadSheet]

Paste to SpreadSheet down below

[image: Paste to SpreadSheet]

Current Code

```
Sub pullSecEquipment()

Dim path As String
Dim ThisWB As String
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim shtPull As Worksheet

Dim Filename As String
Dim Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, DestRng As Range
Dim lRow As Integer
Dim destLRow As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long



Dim UpdateDate As String

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Dim selectedFolder


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    selectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

End With

path = selectedFolder

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False



Set shtDest = Workbooks("GPnewchapterTEST2.xlsm").Worksheets("START")

'clear content of destination table
shtDest.Rows("8:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents


Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls*", vbNormal)

If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
        'MsgBox Filename
        
        '''''
        'SEC
        '''''
        
        If InStr(Filename, "Equipment") <> 0 Then
            
            Dim range1 As Range
            Set range1 = Range("E:K")
            
'For Each Wkb In Application.Workbooks
    'For Each shtDest In Wkb.Worksheets
        'Set shtPull = Wkb.Sheets(1)
            
        'If shtPull.Name Like "*-*" Then

            'last row
            destLRow = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
            '1st row
            lRow = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells.Find(what:="EQUIPMENT DESCRIPTION", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
            'STHours
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = lRow To destLRow

                Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 5).Address, Cells(i, 11).Address)
                Set DestRng = shtDest.Range("O" & shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                
                CopyRng.Copy
                DestRng.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
                Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
                
                Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 1).Address, Cells(i, 1).Address)
                Set DestRng = shtDest.Range("C" & shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlDown).Row)
                
                CopyRng.Copy
                DestRng.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
                Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
                

                Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 3).Address, Cells(i, 3).Address)
                Set DestRng = shtDest.Range("S" & shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)
                
                CopyRng.Copy
                DestRng.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
                Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
                
            
                i = i + 2
            
            Next i

            
            'Dim cell As Integer
            'Dim empname As String
            
            'destLRow = 8 '' find out how to find first available row
            'For cell = 2 To lRow
            
                'empname = Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(cell, 3).Value & " " & Wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(cell, 4).Value
                
                
               ' shtDest.Cells(8, 5).Value = empname
                'shtDest.Cells(8, 1).Value = "Service Electric"
            
            'Next cell
            
            
           ' Wkb.Close Save = False

        End If
        'End If
        
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do in VBA and want to copy one value in **"ALL"** column

```
Cells(1,1).Copy Columns(1)
```